# Twilio functions messages history query

Tags: twilio-functions

I'm using Twilio Functions to look up a previous messages that was sent to from the incoming SMS.

```
exports.handler = function(context, event, callback) {
  const fromNumber = event.From;

  const client = context.getTwilioClient();

  client.messages.list({      
    to: fromNumber,
    limit: 1
  })
  .then((messages) => {
    console.log(`Found message with SID ${messages[0].sid}`);
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });     

};
```

But whatever I try, I can't get any results from the client.message.list(). Any thoughts? Thanks!

Went through twilio documentation. There weren't an exact example for this, but in a similar manner You could create new messages. No error from the console side also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the problem was me. I had callback() call made outside the promise handling, which caused the function to exit before promise was done. More information from if anybody needs

https://www.twilio.com/docs/serverless/functions-assets/functions/invocation